# How do you detect an app open in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can you detect an "app open" in flutter? I'd like to log an event there.

Comment: You can use WidgetsBindingObserver and AppLifeCycleState

Answer (score 2):

Using `WidgetsBindingObserver` we can observer app lifecycle event like

- inactive
- paused
- resumed
- suspending

  ```
  import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
         class YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

          @override
         void initState() {
           super.initState();
           WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
         }


         @override
         void dispose() {
           WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
           super.dispose();
         }


          @override
         void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
           if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
              //do your stuff
           }
         }
       }
  ```

[:Refer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)